# Perl commandline arguments

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I have a question about the commandline arguments in Perl. I'm not sure if someone has asked this question before because I'm not sure what to search for.

I'm having an aaplication where I pass some commandline arguments. But I want it to look like this: `stepanalyzer --file=glasses.STEP --get=#62296,#3,#883`

so I can say `--get` for example. And how I can pass multiple arguments with the `--get`

I hope someone is able to help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which perl module for handling command line arguments do you (intend to) use?

Comment: I use [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) to parse arguments. It [supports](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Options-with-multiple-values) what you want

Comment: Feel free to post an answer. I'm busy right now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The library to use is [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)

**As I said I needed something like `--get="616","718"`**

So with this library you can put: `GetOptions('file=s' => \$file, 'get=s' => \@ary);`

```
'file=s'
```

***Means:*** `--file` needs a string after it.

```
'get=s'
```

***Means:*** The same, where now we can have multiple `--get value` on the command line and each such option adds its string to `@ary`.  Thus the option as a comma-separated list, requested in the question, is one element in the array and one way to expand this is

```
@ary = split(/,/, join(',', @ary));
```

as [shown in documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Options-with-multiple-values)

But there is also another way to give this: `'get=s@'`. What you prefer.